# Creating an instance of a class that implements generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Ok I have a generic interface

```
public IConfigurationValidator<T>
{
 void Validate();
}
```

a class that implements it:

```
public class SMTPServerValidator : IConfigurationValidator<string>
    {


        public void Validate(string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new Exception("Value cannot be null or empty");
            }
        }


    }
```

I now want to use reflection to create an instance of SMTPServerValidator, because I know the AssemblyQualifiedName of the type.

I was thinking to use Activator.CreateInstance and cast that to the interface...
like this:

```
IConfigurationValidator<T> validator = (IConfigurationValidator<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SMTPServerValidator));
```

I dont know what T is....how do I use reflection to create an instance of this class?

There is another class that has that I am dealing with that I left out:

```
public class ConfigurationSetting<T>
    {

        IConfigurationValidator<T> m_Validator;

        public ConfigurationSetting(IConfigurationValidator<T> validator)
        {
            m_Validator = validator;
        }

        public void Validate(T value)
        {
            m_Validator.Validate(value);
        }
    }
```

In the end I am trying to create ConfigurationSettings and need to pass in the appropriate validator based on the parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't the Validate method impl have no parameters?

Comment: I have changed a lot of stuff around...I realized I had other problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the instance of the class is easy - you've done that already with `Activator.CreateInstance`.

If you don't know what `T` is, how are you hoping to *use* this as an implementation of the interface?

I assume that in reality, the interface actually refers to `T` in the members. If it doesn't - or if you don't need those bits - then make it non-generic, or create a non-generic base interface which the base interface extends.

Comment: I have the name of the concrete type (SMTPServerValidator) and want to create an instance but want to use it through the interface.

Comment: It is possible to have a different validator class that implements the interface but with T as an int.  I am willing to go a completely different direction if you have ideas....

Comment: How are you going to *use* the interface if you don't know what T is? What could you validate without knowing the type?

Comment: Yeah...I got a little higher in the logic, and what I was trying to do all fell apart....

Answer (score 0):

In the example given, `T` is `string`.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: All I know going in is that I have a type name, and I know it implements the generic interface, so I want to cast it to the interface from Activator.CreateInstance(), but to cast I need to know what T is but I dont know what it is....since this could be some other class and T could be an int....or any other object type

Answer (score 0):

The class you want to cast to is IConfigurationValidator<string>, as the SMTPServerValidator implements IConfigurationValidator<T>, specifying T as string

Comment: but it could be a different class and T could be an int...but I want to still cast to the interface...so could implement IConfigurationValidator<int>

Comment: Why could it be in IConfigurationValidator<int>? SMTPServerValidator, which is what you're creating an instance of, implements IConfigurationValidator<string>

Answer (score 0):

I realized at a higher layer I do have the type and can create it the way I was initially intending to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Type lConfigValidatorType = typeof(IConfigurationValidator<>)
Type lSomeOtherType = typeof(T)
Type lConstructedType = lConfigValidatorType.MakeGenericType(lSomeOtherType);
var lObject = Activator.CreateInstance(lConstructedType)
```

Comment: You cant create an instance of an Interface.